# Javascript advanced console.log

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Let's assume i have JS code like this:

`var foo = new Array('foo', 'bar');
var bar = new Array();
bar.push(foo);
console.log(bar);`

The console log only gives me:

`Array [ Array[2] ]`

I am looking for way to get true log in console. In this case array with subarrays and so on. Something similar to PHP:

`echo '<pre>' . print_r($bar, TRUE);`

Comment: Use a better browser/dev tools

Comment: @SteveRobbins what do you suggest? Will firebug print me those data?

Comment: In Chrome you can expand the objects http://i.imgur.com/woSwpZC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.dir) instead of `log`. It gives an interactive view.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome/Opera/Firefox all allow for further inspection of arrays via console.log().

Try Firebug also for additional debugging ability.

Answer (score 0):

If your [browser supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=stringify) it, you can also use the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. It's best explained with an example:

```
var a = [ 
  "123", 
  { "foo": "bar" }, 
  [ "inner", "array", [ "inner-inner", "array-array" ] ] 
];
console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );
// "["123",{"foo":"bar"},["inner","array",["inner-inner","array-array"]]]"
```

Basically the function converts objects into a JSON string format allowing you to see each object/array and all of it's sub-elements in a plan, string-like format.

Keep in mind that this method will only be effective if the object you are trying to view only contains simple types of data... Function definitions within objects and more complex built-in objects such as `window` or `document` will not yield useful information.